# Import Data... Loading 99% fail. Help

Tags: database, import

I have problems when importing data. What can I do to fix it ? 99% loading.... fail :(
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add below line at beginning of sql file

> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

and

> SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

at the end of sql file and try to import again.

read more here [MySQL – Disable Foreign Key Checks or Constraints](https://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/)